# PHP Get Twitter username from URL (Regex)

Tags: php, regex, twitter

I'm looking to be able to extract a Twitter username from a URL.

E.g: https://twitter.com/jack => jack

I found this Regex to be helpful.

```
  if (preg_match("/^https?:\/\/(www\.)?twitter\.com\/(#!\/)?(?<name>[^\/]+)(\/\w+)*$/", $url, $regs)) {
    return $regs['name'];
  }
```

It doesn't seem to work when twitter URL contains query parameters.

For example  = `https://twitter.com/jack?lang=en` returns  `jack?lang=en`

Any idea how to improve the regex to prevent this ?

Comment: Or `~https?://(?:www\.)?twitter\.com/\K[^/?#]+~`

Comment: I'd use [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) instead.

Comment: I see. I'll look into that. Thanks @Jeto

Comment: Simply remove the query string `$url = strtok($url, '?');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
preg_match('/https?:\/\/twitter\.com\/(?<name>[^\?]+)\??.*/', 'https://twitter.com/jack?lang=en', $m);
var_dump(trim($m['name']));
```

```php
$path = parse_url('https://twitter.com/jack?lang=en',PHP_URL_PATH);
var_dump(str_replace('/','', $path));
```

```php
string(4) "jack"
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation about the pattern `https?:\/\/twitter\.com\/(?<name>[^\?]+)?\??.*`?  This part `(?<name>[^\?]+)?` is optional. This is also optional `\??` and this `.*` matches any char 0+ times. So all after `https://twitter.com/` is optional and the `.*` will match the whole line.

Comment: It seems I lost in questions. I fixed the regexp. Name part, of course, not optional. The query question mark is optional and all after it also optional. So regexp means: scheme, host, then all until question mark is name, then literally "?" which may be absent and any symbols (or no one) after "?"